# Grouping by dates using floor_date

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have dataset df_period5 like below:

| period5 | Country | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1938-01-01 | France | 120 |
| 1944-01-01 | Zambia | 345 |
| 1960-01-01 | Senegal | 47 |
| 2021-01-01 | Tchad | 38 |

I am trying to group the period5 column by 20 years interval, group by country, and summarize n. Since the dataset does not contain some dates, I'd like to fill the missing dates with the complete function and assign zero to n.

Here's what I have tried:

```
df_period5<-df_period5 %>% 
    group_by(yearbin = lubridate::floor_date(period5, "20 year")) %>%
    summarize(n = sum(n))
```

This code does not take all dates into account and does not group by country.

Here's the raw data:

```
structure(list(period5 = structure(c(-11688, -11688, -7670, -14245, 
-7305, -13149, 7305, -2557, -10592, -14610), tzone = "America/Los_Angeles", class = "Date"), 
    Country = c("cameroun", "tchad", "tchad", "mali", "tchad", 
    "cameroun", "madagascar", "madagascar", "mali", "mali"), 
    n = c(4135L, 2725L, 2479L, 1803L, 1674L, 1264L, 1088L, 1032L, 
    863L, 761L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is my first time using lubridate and I'd really appreciate suggestions to make this work.

Comment: You just need to add `Country` as another argument in `group_by()` so that they are kept separate. As for the dates not being taken account, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you provide an example of your raw data using the `dput()` function to provide the data, along with an example of what the output you are looking for?

Comment: @Phil The code only outputs data from 1879-01-01 to 1979-01-01. My data has observations up to 2019-01-01. I am not sure why it does not cover the whole range of the dataset.

Comment: Could you provide the `dput()` output before running the code you provided above? In the data you provided the latest date was 1990, so I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Phil is your origin date  "1970-01-01 UTC"  is that what ``lubridate::origin``  returns ? actually i implemented the provided data and i didn't have dates in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
df <- structure(list(period5 = structure(c(-11688, -11688, -7670, -14245, 
                                     -7305, -13149, 7305, -2557, -10592, -14610), tzone = "America/Los_Angeles", class = "Date"), 
               Country = c("cameroun", "tchad", "tchad", "mali", "tchad", 
                           "cameroun", "madagascar", "madagascar", "mali", "mali"), 
               n = c(4135L, 2725L, 2479L, 1803L, 1674L, 1264L, 1088L, 1032L, 
                     863L, 761L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                      "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I do not know much about `lubridate` either, so I just work on years from 1879 to 2019 with 8 20-year periods. You may want to adjust those values according to your data.

```
my_breaks <- seq(1879, 2019, by = 20)
df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(
    year = year(period5),
    year20 = cut(year, breaks = my_breaks, labels = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  complete(year20 = seq_along(my_breaks)) %>%
  group_by(Country, year20) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(
    year20 = factor(year20, labels = paste(my_breaks)),
    n = replace_na(n, 0)
  )
```

Results:

```
> df_new    
# A tibble: 32 × 3
# Groups:   Country [4]
   Country    year20     n
   <chr>      <fct>  <int>
 1 cameroun   1879       0
 2 cameroun   1899       0
 3 cameroun   1919    5399
 4 cameroun   1939       0
 5 cameroun   1959       0
 6 cameroun   1979       0
 7 cameroun   1999       0
 8 cameroun   2019       0
 9 madagascar 1879       0
10 madagascar 1899       0
# … with 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```